# How to logout from e-mail?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I've got a big problem. I'm trying to do automatic logout from email. But "logout" button is hidden. In the corner of page is my email adress.

And if I put cursor on this, its expand like this:
[Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCsA4.png)

As you can see, this button is hidden and I have no idea how to get in there and click it to logout. 
There's a HTML code of this object:
[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opWCf.png)

Can you help me, how to logout by using Selenium in C#? Im using FireFoxWebDriver btw.

Comment: wouldn't it be much easier for you to create a simple request to that `url` link which is added to the logout button?

Comment: Maybe. I just tried to describe problem as good as possible.

Comment: I see the button, though. You've named it Wyloguj sie (excuse the spelling) in the HTML, and it's definitely present in the dropdown list..

Comment: That's right. "Wyloguj sie" means "Log Out" by the way. I dont know how to click this button by using Selenium. I tried to Click on submenu first and then "Log Out" but it's not working

Comment: What you should do first write code to mouse hover on setting to enable logout using Action class, After that create code to click on Logout button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JavaScriptExecutor` for same

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By."YOUR LOCATOR");

((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("$('.userDropdown').hover();");
```

.. then it should become enabled and you should normally click it.

Otherwise, post a link to the given page, so i could take a closer look.